# .onchange = () => {}; fires, addEventListener('change', () => {}); does not?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, event-handling, dom-events

First defining

```
selectedOptionElement = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
```

I am struggling to understand why

```
.onchange = () => {};
```

fires whereas

```
addEventListener('change', () => {});
```

does not?

Likewise why would it work with

```
selectedOptionElement = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
```

but not

```
selectedOptionElement = document.getElementById('selectBoxIdName')[0];
```

Testing in Chrome 66.0.3359.181

```
try {
  selectedOptionElement = document.getElementById('projectsSelectBox');
  selectedOptionElement.onchange = () => {
  // selectedOptionElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
    var projectsSelectBox, selectedOption, projectType1, projectType2;
    projectsSelectBox = document.getElementById('projectsSelectBox');
    selectedOption = projectsSelectBox.options[projectsSelectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    projectType1 = document.getElementById('projectType1');
    projectType2 = document.getElementById('projectType2');

    if (selectedOption === '1') {
      projectType2.style.display = "none";
      projectType1.style.display = "block";
    } else if (selectedOption === '2') {
      projectType1.style.display = "none";
      projectType2.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      projectType1.style.display = "block";
      projectType2.style.display = "block";
    }
  };
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: `getElementById` returns the first element, not an array that you can point to an index of. This is correct because you shouldn't have more than one element with an ID. That's why it's an ID.

Comment: The last one is clear, `getElementById` returns a single element. In the case of `select`, `[0]` is the first option of the returned element, which naturally never changes, hence it cannot trigger `change` event. For the other issues, it would be nice if you'd provide a reproducable example, see [mcve].

Comment: In order to debug the first problem you're having can you provide your actual code in a minimal example so we can see what you're doing? Think of it like a mechanic. We can tell you what we think the cause is over the phone, but when the car comes in we can poke around and have a much better chance at diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Updated. The second problem is resolved, thanks for that. Here is my complete code block, it is just a simple filtering switch, the line that DOESN'T work is commented out.

Comment: [Seems to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/6asdLbnh/) ..?

Comment: I see your fiddle works. I agree that it SHOULD work for me. But it's just. not. working.

Answer (score 0):

if you uncomment the `addEventListener` line and remove your `.onchange` line, you'll end up with an error:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

This is resolved by adding a closing parentheses after your closing brace.

```
selectedOptionElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
  var projectsSelectBox, selectedOption, projectType1, projectType2;
  projectsSelectBox = document.getElementById('projectsSelectBox');
  selectedOption = projectsSelectBox.options[projectsSelectBox.selectedIndex].value;
  projectType1 = document.getElementById('projectType1');
  projectType2 = document.getElementById('projectType2');

  if (selectedOption === '1') {
    projectType2.style.display = "none";
    projectType1.style.display = "block";
  } else if (selectedOption === '2') {
    projectType1.style.display = "none";
    projectType2.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    projectType1.style.display = "block";
    projectType2.style.display = "block";
  }
});  // <-- closing paren
```

After doing this, your code will work.

```js
try {
  selectedOptionElement = document.getElementById('projectsSelectBox');
  selectedOptionElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
    var projectsSelectBox, selectedOption, projectType1, projectType2;
    projectsSelectBox = document.getElementById('projectsSelectBox');
    selectedOption = projectsSelectBox.options[projectsSelectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    projectType1 = document.getElementById('projectType1');
    projectType2 = document.getElementById('projectType2');

    if (selectedOption === '1') {
      projectType2.style.display = "none";
      projectType1.style.display = "block";
    } else if (selectedOption === '2') {
      projectType1.style.display = "none";
      projectType2.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      projectType1.style.display = "block";
      projectType2.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="projectsSelectBox">
  <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<p id="projectType1">Option Text</p>
<p id="projectType2">Option Text 2</p>
```

Comment: I know, I didn't include the closing brace in my example, but it is in my code. It doesn't solve my problem. Thanks